# How do I use the value of a variable in a function else where?

Tags: c, variables

I have a certain program that lets you register members and save their name and birthdate into arrays. The particular function that does this registration uses the following code;

```
char regmember (struct member a[])
{

    int i = 0;
    char wow;
    do
    {
        //registration
        printf("\n Do you want to add someone else (y/n):");
        scanf(" %c",&wow);
        i++
    }while(wow != 'n');

    int nrofmembers = i;
    return nrofmembers;
}
```

-> I save the user input by using

`scanf("%s",a[i].name)` and `scanf("%d",&a[i].ID);`

which is why I am using `i++`. As you realize, the int variable `i`, will hold the number of members who have been registered. I want to utilize this info in order to use it in loops in other functions, so I went on to save the value of `i` in another int variable...

```
int nrofmembers = i;
```

---

My problem is, I can't use that variable (`nrofmembers`) else where, even though I tried returning it, any advice?

Comment: Define "Can't use"

Comment: When you call your function `regmember`, you do save the result it returns in some variable? As in `int var = regmember(argument);`? Then you can just pass the variable (`var` in my example) to the other functions that need it.

Comment: you do not return the variable, you return its value

Comment: Where did you declare `wow`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The calling of the function regmember occurs in another "menu" function with a switch command. The user is prompted to choose a certain operation and then the switch command calls regmember. The calling of the function for the menu located in int main, alongside with the creation and opening of a file + fclose and the end. I hope this give a little but more understanding.

Comment: It sounds that you need to start reading your C text book, I suppose there are some fundamental concepts, not even specific to the C language, you didn't understand

Comment: @Jabberwocky, sorry, forget to add the declarations, see edited version.

Comment: For better understanding, please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: your variable can be a parameter and its value returned, or it can be an input-output parameter, see my answer

Comment: About the `//registration` part: I suppose you stripped some code out of here? Please confirm, because otherwise your function doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Jabberwocky visibly it is not the original code, there is no ',' after `i++` etc ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int regmember` instead of `char regmember`? But anyway your question is pretty unclear. You need to read this: [ask] and you need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need both to get *i* in parameter and to return the new value, you can do

```
int regmember (struct member a[], int i)
{
    ... use and modify i

    return i;
}
```

or using it as an input-output variable

```
void regmember (struct member a[], int * i)
{
    ... use and modify *i
}
```

In the first case the caller do for instance :

```
int i = 0;

for (...) {
  ...
  i = regmember(..., i);
  ...
}
```

and in the second case :

```
int i = 0;

for (...) {
  ...
  regmember(..., &i);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Want to use and modify I, so tried the first example. But the second function which calls regmember says " i undeclared ( first use in this function)", Am I supposed to declare int i = 0; in this function as well, if yes, do you mind explaining why?

Comment: it is not mandatory to name the variable _i_ both in the caller and _regmember_ I did to simplify. Where do you have ` i undeclared` ? In my code I define it on both sides. Did you forget to add it in parameter ?

Comment: Ahaa I see now, thanks for the explanation. I have the error in the function that calls for regmember();. regmember looks like this in that function -- regmember(a, i);

Comment: @LesterCrest of course you need also to define the var on the caller side, and don't forget to initialize it to 0  on the caller side.

Comment: oh, almost forgot. Thanks so much @bruno

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you keep the members in a global array, then you can manage how many members are in your array also as a global variable, for example

```
struct member gMembers[MAX_MEMBERS];
int gnMembers;
```

Your function can now operate on this array directly:

```
int regmember (void)
{
    if (gnMembers < MAX_MEMBERS)
    {
        // add member
        if (scanf("%s",gMembers[gnMembers].name)==1
        &&  scanf("%d",&gMembers[gnMembers].ID)==1) {
            gnMembers++;
            return 1; // success
        }
    }
    return 0; // array full or scanf error
}
```